# D3 - change formatting if a column in the data exists

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, formatting

I have a json going to D3:

```
{"time": "foo1", "values1": "bar1", "values2": "val1"}
{"time": "foo2", "values1": "bar2", "values2": "NULL"}
{"time": "foo3", "values1": "bar3", "values2": "val2"}
{"time": "foo4", "values1": "bar4", "values2": "NULL"}
```

It produces a line-graph of `values1` against `time`, with circular points on it, generated, by this:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data);
            circles.exit().remove();
            circles.enter().append("circle")
               .attr("r", 2)
               .merge(circles)
               .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
               .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.values1); });
```

There is then a bit of CSS to define the colour of the circles. This all works fine.

Is it possible to have a circle rendered in a different colour if `values2` from the same time stamp is not NULL?
For example, from line one of the data, a point would sit at `(foo1,bar1)`, and be black, because `values2` is not null, whereas, from the line below, the point would be rendered at `(foo2,bar2)`, and be red, because `values2` is null.

Perhaps two separate sets of circles would be appropriate, this seems the most obvious solution, but I'm still not sure how to implement the condition.

Comment: `.style("fill", function(d){ return d.values2 === "NULL" ? "red" : "black"})`. By the way, `"NULL"` (just a string) is different from `null`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you - if you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: No worries, you can write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:
`.style("fill", function(d){ return d.values2 === "NULL" ? "red" : "black"})`. Answer credit to @GerardoFurtado